# How to remove files from /usr/bin

Tags: uninstall

A few months I accidentally compiled an application that installed several binaries in the /usr/bin folder and then I ran the same installation to place the same binaries in a shared location.
Now, some users are using the binaries in the /usr/bin instead of the shared location.  How can I remove these?  Should I just delete them ?  If so, will this cause any issues?

Here is the list.  Thanks !!

pwd: /urs/bin

```
[root@sever]# ls | grep blast
- blastdb_aliastool
- blastdbcheck
- blastdbcmd
- blast_formatter
- blastn
- blastp
- convert2blastmask
- deltablast
- legacy_blast.pl
- makeblastdb
- blastxz
- tblastx
- psiblast
- rpsblast
- rpstblastn
- tblastn
- update_blastdb.pl
```

Comment: Should you just delete them? Yes, probably, will i t cause issues? For anyone using the /usr/bin location, yes, probably. Is there a reason why using the /usr/bin location is undesirable? if its just a management issue, you could always delete the unwanted location and create a symbolic link between the two places so that current users are undisturbed, assuming there aren't files stored in the deleted location that they need

Answer (score 1):

instead of plain deleting them, if I were you, I would delete and create a link to where your actual binary is placed. This will prevent a lot of headaches for you, especially if you are dealing with less than computer savvy people as your audience. For instance

```
rm /usr/bin/blastdb_aliastool
ln -s /new/shared/location/blastdb_aliastool /usr/bin/blastdb_aliastool
```

and if you repeat this for all the files you delete, people who reference /usr/bin location, will access the location you actually want them to use.

Comment: MelBurslan, thanks for the tip. I will certainly do this.  These applications are running on a cluster where the compute nodes need to "see" the binaries in the shared location; they cannot see any binaries in the /usr/bin from the main head node.     I will follow your advise !!!

Comment: You can avoid `rm` by using `ln -sf ...`